# How can I add third party images to be used in the Phonegap Framework in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, html, cordova

How can I add third party images to be be used in the Phonegap Framework in Xcode?

I have a few images to include.

The linking to the various websites work but the images are not showing, it is just a question mark.

```
<li><a href="http://www.google.se">Google<img src="googlelogo.png"/></a>
```

Please help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to refer to an image that you include with your PhoneGap project. Just make sure any images you want to reference are included inside the **www** folder of your project.

Think of the **www** folder like you would a directory on a server somewhere. Your index.html page sits on the root, and you can create any number of sub-directories you'd like... just as you would on a regular server.

```
<li><a href="http://www.google.se">Google<img src="googlelogo.png"/></a>
```

The above code suggests you have a file at: **www/googlelogo.png**

```
<li><a href="http://www.google.se">Google<img src="myImages/googlelogo.png"/></a>
```

The above code suggests you have a file at: **www/myImages/googlelogo.png**